# WebStorm 2021.1.3 не работает (ctrl+shift+/) для unComment

Tags: webstorm

*WebStorm 2021.1.3* комментирует блок кода правильно (`ctrl+shift+/`), но при нажатии (`ctrl+shift+/`), чтобы `unComment` - не работает - добавляет дополнительные знаки комментирования.
Сталкивался ли кто-либо с таким багом? (*PHPSTORM* у меня все делает правильно)

Comment: `ctrl+/` тогглит комментарии. Если честно, про `ctrl+shift+/` впервые слышу 

Comment: ctrl+/ - это для СТРОК, ctrl+shift+/ -для БЛОКА кода (/*......*/)
--------
проблема только с файлами НЕ .js, например с .php
(похоже все связано с отступами - ctrl+shift+/ добавляет в НЕ .js файлах отступ после /*....., но я так и не нашел как исправить ситуацию)

Comment: Можно исправить ситуацию (File Menu > Settings > File Types > click 'PHP files' > click 'Add' in the bottom screen > enter '*.php'), но тогда подсветка в .php теряется. Мне в webstorm PHP нужен лишь для серверной части на Laravel